# Hide Windows Phone 8.1 CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone app and I have encountered an "issue". I have a  `BottomAppBar` control on my View and some `AppBarButton` controls inside the command bar. I would like to "hide" the `BottomAppBar` in such way that only those three dots on the right side are displayed and the user would have to slide the `BottomAppBar` control up to see its contents.

I have tried to:

1. Set the `IsOpen` property of the CommandBar to False - didn't work
2. Set all the `AppBarButton` controls visibility to `Collapsed` - showed only the empty BottomAppBar

I am not very good at explaining myself, therefore I will add a couple of images from another app on my phone, just to show exactly what I would like to obtain:

[image: <code>BottomAppBar</code> is somehow "collapsed"]
[image: 'BottomAppBar' is opened]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set the ClosedDisplayMode=Minimal

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton IsCompact="True" Label="About"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: That was the option I was looking for! I am not sure how I missed it...Thank you